# How to make visible both icon and text on QML ToolButton

Tags: qt, qml

I am creating desktop application using QML and QtQuick.Components. I want to place on the toolbar buttons like the standard MacOS settings dialogs do: [image: Toolbar]

I use ToolBar and [ToolButton](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquickcontrols/qml-qtquick-controls1-toolbutton.html), but I can't find the way to do it. For instance with the following code it shows icons only:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    // ...

    toolBar: ToolBar {
        RowLayout {
            ToolButton {
                text: qsTr("Main")
                iconSource: "main.png"
            }
            ToolButton {
                text: qsTr("System")
                iconSource: "system.png"
            }
            ToolButton {
                text: qsTr("Items Book")
                iconSource: "itemsbook.png"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it seems like [ToolButton](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-components/desktop/source/1777280fe31f86839089d3e3218061a4f28d93b4:components/ToolButton.qml) can show either text or icon:

```
Text {
    id: textitem
    text: button.text
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    visible: button.iconSource == "" // <=========
}
```

Comment: Any reason for not using Actions like in the [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-controls-texteditor-qml-main-qml.html)?

Comment: @LaszloPapp there is no difference, with Actions only icons are visible too.

Answer (score 7):

A simple yet a powerful approach is to create own QML component.

1. Create a custom QML component / file:
   `File -> New File or Project -> Qt -> QML File (choose latest version)`.
   Now enter file name, for example MyToolButton.
   Note that it will be also used as
   *component name*.
2. Add there neccesary imports and code:

MyToolButton.qml (customize for your needs)

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ToolButton
{
    Image {
        source: parent.iconSource
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit // For not stretching image (optional)
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 2 // Leaving space between image and borders (optional)
        anchors.bottomMargin:10 // Leaving space for text in bottom
    }
    Text {
        text: parent.text

        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom // Placing text in bottom
        anchors.margins: 2 // Leaving space between text and borders  (optional)
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter // Centering text
        renderType: Text.NativeRendering // Rendering type (optional)
    }
}
```

---

Main.QML (where you want to use it):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

// Usual toolbar declaration
ToolBar {
    id: mainToolBar
    RowLayout {

        // Create MyToolButton. Note that component name (MyToolButton) is the same as file name.
        MyToolButton {
            id:tbQuit

            // Way 1: Add here any icon 
            iconSource: "qrc:///images/quit.png" 
            text:qsTr("&Quit")

            // Way 2, my favourite: Convert your Action into Button!
            action: actQuit
        }
    }
}

Action {
    id: actQuit
    text: qsTr("&Quit")
    onTriggered: Qt.quit()
    shortcut: "Alt+Q"
    iconSource: "qrc:///Images/Exit.png"
}
```

---

**Notes:**

1. It requires QtQuick.Controls 1.4 and should work on Qt 5.2+. (Worked fine on Qt 5.5).
2. Don't forget to add *imports*.
3. Code parts marked as `(optional)` can be skipped.
4. Replace `ToolButton` with `Button` and it will work as a Button.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Doesn't really work in Qt 5.6. I tried and the other answer below by @Kirween but toolbar height can't be adjusted. The text element just overlaps with the image no matter what I do. It is just fattened out.

Answer (score 4):

Have you try to add your own `Text` control like this:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    // ...

    toolBar: ToolBar {
        RowLayout {
            ToolButton {
                text: qsTr("Main")
                iconSource: "main.png"
                Text {
                    text: parent.text
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                }
            }
            ToolButton {
                text: qsTr("System")
                iconSource: "system.png"
                Text {
                    text: parent.text
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                }
            }
            ToolButton {
                text: qsTr("Items Book")
                iconSource: "itemsbook.png"
                Text {
                    text: parent.text
                    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And set the `ToolButton` height with the right value (image + text height)

Comment: Looks well, but there is empty space above the icon.

Comment: Also you can add `anchors.bottomMargin: 2` to Text for being nicer